# SQL add empty rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to add empty rows to a SQL SELECT statement in such a way that the result is in multiples of 10, meaning if there are 8 rows in a Tables 2 empty Rows should be added so that the select statement has 10 rows and if there are say 16 rows in a Table 4 empty rows should be added so that the select statement has 20 rows etc, etc.

In short at all times the rows selected must be 10,20,30,40, etc, etc.

Comment: Which database are you using (e.g. Postgres, SQL Server, Oracle) ?

Comment: Sorry about that, I a using SQL Server

Comment: SQL is the language SQL-Server is a product from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL something like this should do the job:

```
select mycol from mytable 
  union all
select null from generate_series(1,round((select count(*)+4 from mytable),-1))
```